# If two languages are polytime reducable, does that imply they are also turing reducable

Tags: computability, reductions, polynomial-time-reductions

Is it possible for a pair of languages where A ≤T B but not A ≤p B?

I am not sure if this could be the case since a turning reduction would imply we can use a decider for one language to decide another.

Comment: Your title makes no sense, please edit it. Also, try not to mispell [Turing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Turing)'s name

Comment: @Nathaniel changed the title

Comment: The title and the body contain opposite questions.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: take $A=\emptyset$ and some $B\in R\setminus P$ where $R$ is the set of all recursive languages.

Comment: I am not sure how R/P would help in this case.

Comment: I have answered the qeustion in the body of the post.